# XML getElementsByTagName() and querySelectorAll() return end tags

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, getelementsbytagname

I am parsing an XML document in browser using JavaScript. The XML is something like this:

```
<product product_id='266629' name='Pink Net Ankle Socks' sku_number='00100003396'>
  <category>
    <primary>Accessories</primary>
  </category>
  <description>
    <short>Pink Net Ankle SocksThese light and airy fish net style socks are ideal for wearing with ankle style shoe boots. - Ankle length- 84% Nylon, 16% Elastane</short>
  </description>
</product>
<product product_id='266630' name='Nude Spot Ankle Socks' sku_number='00100003397'>
  <category>
    <primary>Accessories</primary>
  </category>
  <description>
    <short>Nude Spot Ankle SocksThese light and airy socks are ideal for wearing with ankle style shoe boots. - Ankle length- 90% Nylon, 10% Elastane</short>
  </description>
</product>
```

So I'm using `getElementsByTagName()` or `querySelectorAll()` to get all `<product>` elements and then iterate through the resulting array:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","35605_3307557_26408825_cmp.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
var myXmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var products = myXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('product');
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    doSomething(products[i]);
}
```

The problem is that `products` contains ending tags as well! I.e. `products[0]` is a healthy element with all info I need, and `products[1]` is just an empty element with no attributes and inner contents (I assume that's because it's `</product>`), `products[2]` is okay and so on.

I'm working around this by iterating through elements with even indices only (`i += 2`) but that feels very wrong.

How can I get an array of elements without end tags?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://codepen.io/dorward/pen/grXZNN?editors=0012

Comment: Are you free to use JQuery ? If yes i can try this

Comment: I can use jQuery, or write a parser using .NET whatever. I was just wondering how to get rid of end tags using standard JavaScript only. My browser is Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Quentin, I'm parsing XML in different way, see updated post.